# Cannot find the class for Zurb Foundation 6 dropdown :after

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Does anyone know what class I need to overwrite in order to change the colour of the down arrow in a menu item with drop down options?

I cannot find it anywhere!

Code:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="active">About Us</a>
    <ul class="vertical menu nested">
        <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom class of your to change the arrow color like

*<sup>Note: `.your-class` is a dummy class here..you can use your own</sup>*

```
.your-class.dropdown.menu.vertical>li.opens-right>a::after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
}
```

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
.your-class.dropdown.menu.vertical>li.opens-right>a::after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css" />
<ul class="your-class vertical dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu="iet608-dropdown-menu" style="max-width: 250px;" role="menubar" data-is-click="false">
  <li role="menuitem" class="is-dropdown-submenu-parent opens-right" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Item 2" data-is-click="false">
    <a href="#Item-2">Item 2</a>
    <ul class="vertical menu nested submenu is-dropdown-submenu first-sub" data-submenu="" role="menu" style="">
      <li role="menuitem" class="is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#Item-2A">Item 2A</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem" class="is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#Item-2B">Item 2B</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#Item-3">Item 3</a></li>
  <li role="menuitem"><a href="#Item-4">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```